# Dynamic input name attribute in angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way to get Angular to interpret strings inside an `<input>`'s name attribute?

We have a setup like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things">
    <div ng-show="form['something' + thing.name].$error.required">Field is required</div>

    <input type="text" required name="something{{thing.name}}" ng-model="thing.name">
</div>
```

Now, this obviously does not work because angular does not interpret `name="something{{thing.name}}"`.

Is there some way to do this besides writing a custom directive to have a dynamic name attribute?

Comment: IDTTMWYTIM. Do you mean _interpret_?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen possibly... fixed :)

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource that seems to answer my question, voting to close. Thanks